# Synchronous encryption/decryption in C# with TPM 2.0 (3DES, TripleDES, TDES)

Tags: c#, encryption, 3des, tpm

I am trying to use TPM 2.0 in C# with Microsoft.TSS library for encryption/decryption of data.

Access to the TPM and get some random data already works, but that was an easy task.

Here is the code:

```
using Tpm2Lib;

...

//
// Create the device according to the selected connection.
// 
Tpm2Device tpmDevice = new TbsDevice();

//
// Connect to the TPM device. This function actually establishes the
// connection.
// 
tpmDevice.Connect();

//
// Pass the device object used for communication to the TPM 2.0 object
// which provides the command interface.
// 
var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);

byte[] b = tpm.GetRandom(16);
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(b);

//
// Clean up.
// 
tpm.Dispose();
```

I am new in the TPM world and want to achieve the following:

- Store the private 3DES key once in the TPM (so it can not be read)
- Encrypt/decrypt data with the use of TPM

My first question: is this technically possible with the TPM?

After digging into various articles from MS and others, I think it's a little bit complicated and the various samples on github... have not brought light into it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reason to use an obsolete encryption algorithm?

Comment: I think you are trying to use TPM for the not direct purpose

Comment: @JonasH No no reason, also an AES example would be usefull.

Comment: @SergShevchenko Do you mean that i cannot use TPM for direct decryption/encryption?

Comment: I thought you want to set and store private key for TMP, I do not think it is possible